# Python put together GUI and a programm with plot

Tags: python, user-interface

I am writting a program for my job and I'm really just a beginner.

I have already written this code:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')

fixed_df = pd.read_csv('/home/oem/Desktop/Prog/ex.pp-ser', sep='\t', encoding='latin1', decimal = ',',  index_col='time (s)')

fixed_df[:3]
fixed_df.plot(kind='scatter', x='pa,1', y='pc,1', color='black')
```

and this one for GUI

```
import fileinput

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

import pandas as pd

root = Tk(  )

root.geometry('200x150') 


def OpenFile():
    df = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/home/oem/Desktop/Prog/",
                           filetypes =(("CSV", "*.csv"),("All Files","*.*")),
                           title = "Choose a file.")




Title = root.title( "File Opener")

label = ttk.Label(root)

label.pack()


menu = Menu(root)

root.config(menu=menu)

file = Menu(menu)

file.add_command(label = 'Open', command = OpenFile)

file.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = lambda:exit())

file.add_command(label = 'Plot', command = plot_graph)

menu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)





root.mainloop()
```

And I don't know, how can I put the first program in the second one.

It would be really good, when somebody could help me.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to ask, please elaborate more.

Comment: I am trying to write a plot programm with a graphic user interface. I have a lot of csv data and I have already written the programm, that read csv and plot some columns. And now I try to write a gui, then other people can use it, without having development environment.

Comment: Sorry, my english ist bad, I know

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` has a `FigureCanvasTkAgg` which will allow you to draw in a tkinter window. See an example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html).